Do not ask for LUKS password at boot
LUKS is used on a Ubuntu 22 PC to encrypt the whole disk.
So, each time the PC is booted, 2 passwords are requested: LUKS password to decrypt the disk, then the login password to log in.
Is it possible to enter only the login password when LUKS is used to encrypt the disk ?

Only if you remove  the encryotion/luks.

Two passwords are needed because two different things need to be unlocked. It's like first unlocking the gate to get into your property and then unlocking the front door to get into your house.
Once the disk is encrypted, the only way to get to it is using the password. Unless you never turn it off. It is not possible to have the disk encrypted without requiring a password to unlock it on turn on. It needs to be decrypted to be able to use it, and it is decrypted by using the password. It's the only way.
The only thing you could do is remove the password to log in to your desktop. Then you would only need to use the one mandatory password to unlock the encrypted drive.

You are just repeating what the comment to the question says.

Ok but encrypting the disk using Windows bitlocker does not required an extra password. Why can't we get the same feature on Linux ?
